# mysql trigger on insert many to many

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert, many-to-many

I have two tables with many to many relationship.
The tables are

```
table user
idUser
name

table right
idRight
type

table user_has_right
idUser
idRight
```

When I insert a user with the rights I want him to have,
obviously the middle table (user_has_right) must have some inserts
too. Let's say I want to insert the user with id = 1 and name = 'test'
and right = 'boss' , where boss is already a row in table right with id = 1 . 
The middle table must have an insert of (1,1).
I know how to do this programmatically, but can this be done with trigger on insert?

Thank you.

//The problem I'm facing is how to find the idRight for type 'boss'. Maybe a nested select inside the trigger?

//Is this task even possible?

Comment: how should the trigger know, which rights to give which user?

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to ask if this is even possible in the first place.

Comment: I got the solution for your question the same my question

[SQL Server trigger insert values from new row into another table with many-to-many relationship][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246697/sql-server-trigger-insert-values-from-new-row-into-another-table-with-many-to-ma/16251097#16251097

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across this old question. If you're still interested in an answer then here it is

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_user_insert
AFTER INSERT ON `user`
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO user_has_right (idUser, idRight)
  SELECT NEW.idUser, idRight
    FROM `right`
   WHERE type = 'boss';
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a847/3)** demo

Comment: I had forgotten about this one. I found the answer but I forgot to post an answer to close it. This is great though, thanks. 
PS. SQLFiddle? I had no clue. Amazing. Upvoted and accepted.