# SQL Server trigger insert values from new row into another table with many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, relationship, triggers

I have three tables:

- tbl_profiles
- tbl_options
- tbl_profileOption

with many-to-many relationship

[image]

what the insert trigger on `tbl_options` I have to use to add the new options to each profile on `tbl_profiles`, by default value of `isChoose` is `0`

and on the opposite side when insert a new profile binding it with all options on `tbl_options`

In other words :

If I add new Option (4....E) to  `tbl_option`, the trigger must be insert two new rows on `tbl_profileOption`:

```
1....4.......0
2....4.......0
```

I hope that my question is clear,

Answer (score 1):

thank for all who try to help me... I got the solution

- first trigger on `tbl_option`

  ```
  go
  Create TRIGGER insertProfileToOption
  ON dbo.tbl_options
  AFTER INSERT
  AS
  insert into tbl_profileOption (profileOption_profileId,
    profileOption_optoinId)
  (select tbl_profiles.profile_id, @@IDENTITY from tbl_profiles)
  ```
- second trigger on `tbl_profile`

  ```
  go
  Create TRIGGER insertOptionToProfile
  ON dbo.tbl_profiles
  AFTER INSERT
  AS
  insert into tbl_profileOption (profileOption_profileId,
    profileOption_optoinId)
  (select @@IDENTITY, tbl_options.option_id from tbl_options)
  ```

if there is another solution this will be good, thank you